# How do I position my banner and navigation bar with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am looking to create a website but I am having a bit of trouble. I see all these different terms like floating and boxing etc etc but I am confused what I use to position the items. Here is a very good example of what I mean on this website http://happycog.com/

How do I make it so that the header is a certain space of the screen, the navigation another and the area below another and the footer another etc etc.

If you understand what I mean and could direct me towards some help/tutorials I would appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add on to pomologue's answer, one thing that might be confusing you about the site you're looking at, is that they are fixing the menu bar to that top of the screen when the user scrolls. They are doing that with **javascript**, so don't beat yourself up if you can't do it with CSS! If you really want to do that in js, comment back and i'll give you some pointers :)

Answer (score 0):

View Source and Firebug/Web Inspector are your friends. At its simplest, what you want to do is just a series of `<div>` tags with styling.

```
<div id="header">...</div>
<div id="navigation">...</div>
<div id="content">...</div>
<div id="footer">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The website you're giving is just putting divs one after another :

```
    <div id="first block"> ... </div>
    <div id="second block"> ... </div>
```

If you want a similar result, maybe this will help : http://www.insitedesignlab.com/how-to-make-a-single-page-website/

Answer (score 0):

From the example you posted, you're looking for something called a **sticky-header/persistent-header.**

Chances are to get what you're asking for will involve JavaScript since the example you cited is locked to a particular div **and** a screen position.

If you're only looking for the persistent header part where the header stays only at the top constantly, no matter what - then this link has a great implementation in CSS:

http://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/sticky-header-and-footer-using-css/

As for the more dynamic one like http://happycog.com/, then CSS-Tricks has a great tutorial, but it involves JQuery, too.

http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/

DEMO: http://css-tricks.com/examples/PersistantHeaders/

Moreover, Google, Firebug/Chrome Developer Tools and other related tools are your friends.

Good luck!